# Allowing members to upload photos to their profile

Tags: plugins, membership

I am looking for a little bit of direction. I am building a membership site that will allow the user to upload multiple photos for their profile.

My question is: Is their a membership plugin that will allow them to do this. Also, this feature needs to be front end accessible. I do not want the members to ever see the back end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to install an extra plugin for that, there are a lot of them =)

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-photo/

Comment: **front end** – read that? ;)

Comment: @Conrad, it is obvious that I need a plugin. If that is the best advice you can give, then that does not help me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Front-End Users](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/front-end-users) plugin?

Please go through the documentation [example hooks](http://github.com/tombenner/front-end-users/blob/master/example_hooks.php) on how to modify it. I think it will fulfill your needs. Hope that helps.

marikamitsos

Comment: That answer is definetly in the right direction to the solution that I seek.